# Jenkinsfile - calling multiple groovy scripts

Tags: jenkins

We have our shared libraries on gitlab called `mainlibrary` and it has a lot of groovy files.

Example in mainlibrary gitlab repo we have the following files.

```
startup_pipeline.groovy
cleanup_pipeline.groovy
```

In one of our Jenkins job we need to include multiple groovy files in the `Jenkinsfile`. Is this possible?

This is how the `Jenkinsfile` looks like:

```
@Library('mainlibrary')_
startup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com')
```

Can I include the second groovy function file into this `Jenkinsfile` like this?

```
@Library('mainlibrary')_
startup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com'),
cleanup_pipeline(email:'example@example.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the [official docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps) you can include as many custom steps (each in their own .groovy file) in your shared library as you like.